# div to show select menu value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a question regarding Jquery

```
    <select id="thechoices">
<option value="0">Select Box</option>
<option value="box1">Box 1</option>
<option value="box2">Box 2</option>
<option value="box3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIV -->
<div id="value"> disabled till you make a choice</div>
```

while the select menu have the choice Select box i need the div to be shown as a small black screen with the disabled message 
once the user change the select menu and choose another option the value div shown the selected option for example Box 1 or Box 2

Comment: And what's the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sHqFX/

```
<select id="thechoices">
<option value="0">Select Box</option>
<option value="box1">Box 1</option>
<option value="box2">Box 2</option>
<option value="box3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIV -->
<div id="value"></div>
```

Put this between head tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thechoices").change(function(){

       if($(this).val() == 0)
       {
           $("#value").html("disabled till you make a choice");
            $("#value").css("background-color","black");
                 $("#value").css("color","white");
       }
        else{
            $("#value").html($("#thechoices option:selected").text());
            $("#value").css("background-color","white");
            $("#value").css("color","black");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this one working but only when embedding code with in the body tags but i need to be included within the head tags

Comment: @Fouad, i modified the code so it can easily be inserted between the head tags

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // event triggered when options changed
    $('#thechoices').change(function() {
        // check if first option or other is selected
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
            $('#value').addClass('disabled');
            $('#value').html($('#value').data('default'));
        } else {
            $('#value').removeClass('disabled');
            $('#value').html($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwKfP/1/

Comment: excellent  thank you 
only 1 issue 
when selecting another option then back to 0 value to option it doesn't show the disabled message

Comment: @Fouad: it does on my browser. Anyway check out the edited fiddle in answer

Comment: @PeeHaa Nice solution
@Fowad My solution solves that issue, just take a look

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution, just add this code:

CSS:

```
<style>
  .disabled{
    background-color: gray;
  }
</style>
```

JavaScript

```
function onSelectedOption(){
   var selectedText = $("#thechoices option:selected").text();
   if($("#thechoices").val() == "0")
     $('#value').addClass("disabled").text(selectedText );
   else
     $('#value').removeClass("disabled").text("");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  onSelectedOption(); //With this we 'disable' when page loads
  $('#thechoices').change(onSelectedOption);
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery 'change' event. http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('#thechoices').change(function(){
    $('#value').css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#thechoices').change(
  function() {
    $('#value').text(
      $('#thechoices :selected').text()
    )
  }
);
```